# Python Script won't run as a scheduled task on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple recurring tasks scheduled to run several times per day to keep some different data stores in sync with one another. The settings for the 'Actions' tab are as follows:

Action: Start a Program

Program/script: `C:\<path to script>.py`

Add arguments:

Start in: `C:\<directory of script>`

I can run the python files just fine if I use the command line and navigate to the file location and use python  or even just using python  without navigating.

For some reason, the scripts just won't run with a scheduled task. I've checked all over and tried various things like making sure the user profile is set correctly and has all of the necessary privileges, which holds true. These scripts have been working for several weeks now with no problems, so something has changed that we aren't able to identify at this time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions under properties -> security if the user "SYSTEM" has the execute permission for the python files.  The other option is to try placing FULL_PATH/python.exe in front of the script names.

Comment: I have checked all user security permissions and everything looks good. Furthermore, nothing related to user permissions has changed, so I am confident in ruling that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

Action: Start a Program

Program/script: `C:\<path to python.exe>\python.exe`

Add arguments:  `C:\\<path to script>\\script.py`

Comment: That is a good suggestion but also doesn't work. The task runs as expected and I no longer have the 0x1 error code, but the actual python script does not run.

Comment: It turns out this was a simple issue that should have been caught quicker. The default program that opens .py files on the machine was changed from Notepad to PyCharm. Problem solved!